# Search all Google Contacts under same domain

Tags: search, google-contacts

I'm using Google Contacts and I want to search for all contacts ending with `@example.com`.

I tried `@example.com` and  `*@example.com` but it isn't working

How do I do this?

Comment: @donvoter huh ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put the domain by itself (e.g., "example.com") in the search field and go.

I just tried it and I'm shocked how many people I know still have aol.com addresses.